# Symfony: check if sessions exists in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a way to check if a session exists in the twig file? I want to switch between register or logout in my nav bar based on the session of the user.

I've searched a bit around and I could only found solution that do it in the controller.

Comment: `{{ app.session.get('key') }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly checking session variables, I think you want to use what [Symfony already has built-in](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) to handle this. Please see [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#retrieving-the-user-in-a-template):

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    // show logout link
{% else %}
    // show register link
{% endif %}
```

If you are using a Symfony version [earlier than 2.8](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html#access-control-in-templates) you need to check for the existence of `app.user` first:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was looking at the wrong page on symfony (sessions).

Comment: Yep, it did, thnx